# Iptables rules slow down loggining in via SSH

Tags: ssh, iptables, firewall

I am trying to build some basic iptables rules for my VDS:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

I want to block any incoming traffic except for traffic SSH and WEB. But after applying the rules and rebooting the system, it takes 30 seconds to login via SSH, the login process is very slow, but it works perfectly after I connect.

What rules should I add to make loggining in via SSH faster?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/85602/iptables-l-pretty-slow-is-this-normal

http://serverfault.com/questions/416537/why-does-a-valid-set-of-iptables-rules-slow-my-server-to-a-crawl

Answer (score 2):

From `iptables --help`:

```
--numeric   -n      numeric output of addresses and ports
```

https://serverfault.com/questions/85602/iptables-l-pretty-slow-is-this-normal

Include the `-n` option so it doesn't try to use DNS to resolve names for every IP address, network and port. Then it will be fast.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

Allowing Established Sessions

We can allow established sessions to receive traffic:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

If the line above doesn't work, you may be on a castrated VPS whose provider has not made available the extension, in which case an inferior version can be used as last resort:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

---

edited out because help.ubuntu.com offers a better and completer sollution **ignore below**

https://serverfault.com/questions/416537/why-does-a-valid-set-of-iptables-rules-slow-my-server-to-a-crawl

Rule to accept traffic based on existing traffic

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Tried to add the last one `iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT` and get an error `No chain/target/match by that name`

Comment: And could you tell me where should I put `--numeric   -n      numeric output of addresses and ports`

Comment: @Mr.twister: The `--numeric   -n` thing is for when listing stuff with iptables, nothing to do with your problem, at least as I understand it. You need the `iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT` rule. You should also have a `iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT` rule. However, I can not recreate your issue on one of my test servers. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, and this one does not work as well `iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT` — I get the same error.

Comment: try starting over and following iptablesHowTo. also the order of the rules matter, if you accept something then deny the rest and then try to add a rule that allows again strange things happen. you need to add rules in a specific order and ending with a drop(i believe).

Comment: I tried. And the error persists.

Comment: what does 'lsmod|grep tables" return? https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=189186

Answer (score -1):

I solved the same problem after running the following two commands

```
# Allow Established and Related Incoming Connections
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISH
ED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow Established Outgoing Connections
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

These two commands come from [Iptables Essentials: Common Firewall Rules and Commands](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/iptables-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands).

Comment: Does the answer solve OP's problem?